# Flash on IE9 is broken?

Tags: flash, internet-explorer-9

After the latest Adobe Flash update, websites with Flash banners appear really weird in IE9: The banners are placed wrong on the page, covering content and they're flickering (flashing?).

I've tried uninstalling Flash completely and reinstalling it again, but it didn't help.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tired 'rolling back' and installing an older version of Flash?
You can get the older versions from [here](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/142/tn_14266.html)

Comment: Excellent, it worked! :) Thanks for the pointer...